# Can't do date ranges in range with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to filter a specific model using FastAPI using range, but for some reason I cannot.

In Django, I was able to identify the range with `filter(created_at__range=[today, end_day])`, but when I do the same with FastAPI, I get `TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword However, when I do the same thing with FastAPI, I get the error` TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'created_at__range'`.

```py
tas = db.query(models.Task).filter(created_at__range=[today, end_day]).all()
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me more about it.

Comment: Which ORM do you use?

Comment: It seems like you're using SQLAlchemy, so this is more of an SQLAlchemy question than FastAPI, but: `.filter(models.Task.created_at >= today, models.Task.created_at <= end_day)` should do what you want (given that you want to include the end day as well).

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple condition with fillter

for ex :

```
filter(objectModel.created_at >= today).fillter(objectModel.created_at <= end_day).all()
```

object is your model and created_at is your field at database